# How do I remove some attributes of an element using selection by querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I get the correct elements here, the attributes are just not removed when I look at the style, is my method wrong? How do I do it correctly? Thanks!

```
var axes = document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-axis-labels');
       for (var i = 0; i < axes.length; i++) {
           if (i == 1) {
               axes[i].removeAttribute("position");
                axes[i].removeAttribute("height");                    
                axes[i].removeAttribute("top");
                axes[i].removeAttribute("width");
                axes[i].removeAttribute("left");
                axes[i].removeAttribute("margin-top");                  

                //axes[i].css('margin-top', '0px');
            }
```

Comment: The removeAttribute function will only remove things that are (or would be) present in the element's html. That is to say, If the element has a css rule applied, this function will not impact upon the css- you either need to change the element's class, id or (more radically) alter the css rule that applied to the element or simply add inline-style to the element to override the Css. Rob's answer explains the function of `removeAttribute` well.

Comment: What is the purpose of removing attrs ?

Answer (score 1):

`.removeAttribute()` is to remove attributes of an html element

*eg*

on html ( `<div data-test="test" id="test"></div>` )

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('test').removeAttribute('data-test');
```

---

What you are looking for is to remove style properties, so would be like

```
document.getElementById('test').style.width="";
```

---

**Update ,** looking at your q, what you might be looking to remove all styles. If so -

*eg*

on html (`<div id="test" style="position:absolute;top:10px;left:10px">test</div>`)

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('test').removeAttribute('style');
```

Comment: Nope, sorry for misleading, but I want to remove a few attributes in my style.css file not inside html, what happens is in highcharts,  highcharts-axis-labels refer to the y-axis labels and the x-axis ones, I set some attributes for the x-axis, now the y-axis is affected which should not be and that's what I wanted to remove.

Comment: I tried  axes[i].currentStyle.top = "0px"; but doesn't work, too. It's in IE8 and I'm having hard time fixing this issue just in IE8

Comment: if it is in the css, how about changing the class instead. .. `axes[i].className = 'differentcssClass` ?

Comment: Yep! That's what I did when removing attributes seemed futile and it's all working now! Thanks